# Is there a language where presence/absence of V-O agreement would reflect presence/absence of accusative case?

Tags: syntax, cases, agreement

I am trying to find a language which would show the following pattern with respect to agreement/morphological Case:

```
presence of verb-object morphological agreement yields accusative morphology
absence of verb-object morphological agreement yields no accusative morphology
```

This pattern would look quite similar to English tense/subjective (or nominative) case:

```
infinitival clauses yield no subjective case (e.g., For him to win would be surprising)
non-infinitival clauses yield subjective case (e.g., She left yesterday at 6 P.M)
```

If such a language has a pattern which resembles tense/case pattern of English but in relation to the accusative, it would also be interesting.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, German, which does not have verb-object morphological agreement (subject-verb, yes; verb-object, no), but certainly has lots of accusative morphology on most nouns, pronouns, and adjectives, might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @jlawler, mmm no, this is not what I'm looking for. I want to find a language which would show verb-object agreement only when accusative case is realised. Otherwise, i.e., when no accusative is realised, no verb-object morphology is found.

Comment: OK, so **if** a language already has V-O agreement, and **if** it marks accusative case, then you're looking for conditions in that language where agreement fails without an accusative. Can't help you much there; the only languages I ever worked on with object agreement were Mayan, and they're ergative to start with, so no V-O.

Comment: @jlawler thank you, but it would be helpful too, is there a such a pattern of case and agreement in Mayan similar to the English above (but related to Object & Verb)

Comment: Since Mayan languages are ergative, there is no such thing as "Object", nor "Accusative".

Comment: I see now. Thank you